# How can I test Sandbox related functionality without using Production itself as my test environment?

Tags: tooling-api, java, wsdl, tools

I am trying to build tooling around sandbox management but pretty much got stumped by how I would even test this without using Production.

My client app is intended to be build on Java and using the wsc. I got the tooling wsdl and started building my client but got stumped as the whole purpose of this tool is to query information on SandboxInfo and SandboxProcess objects and use that for further actions. This would not make sense in a sandbox since I do not even have a way to query these objects. So, how can I go about developing and testing this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Would help immensely if downvoters also comment here WHY they downvote questions. The reason anyone would ask a question is when they are looking for help. If the purpose of this board is to NOT provide help, then I'm not sure what purpose is being served.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signup for a free enterprise edition. This org is available for 30 days. So you can create many sandboxes here and test your modules. Basically this free trial org acts as a production environment.

Link - https://www.salesforce.com/eu/form/signup/freetrial-sales-ee/

Comment: Makes sense! Yes, will try this, thanks.